# How to read excel (.xlsm) file, that file is using finansu add-in through C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a excel (.xlsm) file with stock markets live data update through the excel add-in "finansu". 
When I try to read excel data through the C# application in stock name column it shows the proper stock name but at the value column it does not show any thing. That stock value column is updated live values through the finansu add-in.

Please help me out to read these values as well.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the source code:

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended   Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";"; 

query = "SELECT * FROM [RealTime$]"; 
conn = new OleDbConnection(connString); 

 if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
   conn.Open(); 

cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn); 
 da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd); 
 dt = new System.Data.DataTable(); 
 da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

OLEDB won't be able to retrieve the data you want.  I'm not familiar with the finansu add-in, but Excel Interop should be able to get what you need.

[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filename = @"C:\temp\Book1.xlsx";
            var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            var wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
            Worksheet realtime = wb.Sheets["RealTime"];

            foreach (Range row in realtime.UsedRange.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", row.Cells[1, 1].Value); // Column A
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", row.Cells[1, 2].Value); // Column B
                // etc ...
            }

            wb.Close(SaveChanges: false);
        }
    }
}
```